# How to do named command line arguments in Bash Scripting better way?

Tags: bash, command, arguments, line, named

This is my sample **Bash Script** *example.sh*:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # Reading arguments and mapping to respective variables
 while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
   if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
        v="${1/--/}"
        declare $v
   fi
  shift
 done

 # Printing command line arguments through the mapped variables
 echo ${arg1}
 echo ${arg2}
```

Now if in terminal I run the bash script as follows:

```
$ bash ./example.sh "--arg1=value1" "--arg2=value2"
```

I get the correct output like:

```
value1
value2
```

Perfect! Meaning I was able to use the values passed to the arguments --arg1 and --arg2 using the variables ${arg1} and ${arg2} inside the bash script.

**I am happy with this solution for now as it serves my purpose, but, anyone can suggest any better solution to use named command line arguments in bash scripts?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$arg1"
echo "$arg2"
```

No parsing needed. From the command line:

```
$ arg1=foo arg2=bar ./example.sh
foo
bar
```

There's even a shell option to let you put the assignments anywhere, not just before the command:

```
$ set -k
$ ./example.sh arg1=hello arg2=world
hello
world
```

Comment: What is "set -k" is for? I like that solution but that is compulsory to do before triggering the bash script passing arguments. Anything to handle that automatically?

Comment: No, because it's the *calling* shell that needs to support it.